# How can I search with the value item instead of key in Exists method dictionary with Vbscript?

Tags: dictionary, vbscript

```
Dim d   ' Create a variable.
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
d.Add "a", "Athens"   ' Add some keys and items.
d.Add "b", "Belgrade"
d.Add "c", "Cairo"
```

Question:
can I write a logic to check `d.Exists("Cario")` value intead of key `d.Exists("c")`
??

Comment: Thanks this means lot to me!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Items Method helps us to get the values stored in the key value pair of the data dictionary object.

`object.Items( )`

---

```
Option Explicit
Dim d,Capital,i,Capital2Search
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
d.Add "a", "Athens"   ' Add some keys and items.
d.Add "b", "Belgrade"
d.Add "c", "Cairo"

'Items Method helps us to get the values stored in the key value pair of the data dictionary object.
'object.Items( )

Capital = d.items

For i=LBound(Capital) to UBound(Capital)
    wscript.echo Capital(i)
Next

'Searching for Cairo
Capital2Search = "Cairo"

For i=LBound(Capital) to UBound(Capital)
    If Instr(UCASE(Capital(i)),UCASE(Capital2Search)) > 0 Then
        wscript.echo Capital2Search & " Exists ! " 
    End If
Next
```

---

***EDIT : 13/08/2020 @18:00***

Refer to your last comment : You can do something like that :

---

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title : Title = "Find a Service by Name"
Dim Dico,objWMIService,colListOfServices,objService,Keys,ServiceName,Service2Search
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colListOfServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service")
Set Dico = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
' We fill our Dictionary in this loop For ... Next
For Each objService in colListOfServices
    If Not dico.Exists(objService.Name) Then
        Dico.Add objService.Name,objService.PathName
    End If
Next

Service2Search = "Bits"
Keys = Dico.Keys

' Looking for a service name = "BITS" in this example :
For each ServiceName in Keys
    If Instr(UCASE(ServiceName),UCASE(Service2Search)) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "The service "& ServiceName & " : Exists !" & vbcrlf &_
        "PahName : " & dico(ServiceName),vbInformation,Title
        'Exit For
    End If
Next
```

---

***EDIT : 13/08/2020 @ 19:30***

If you want to search into an array of services :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title : Title = "Find a Service by Name into an Array"
Dim Dico,objWMIService,colListOfServices,objService,Keys
Dim ServiceName,Services,ArrService2Search,Service2Search,PathName
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colListOfServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service")
Set Dico = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
' We fill our Dictionary in this loop For ... Next
For Each objService in colListOfServices
    If Not dico.Exists(objService.Name) Then
        Dico.Add objService.Name,objService.PathName
    End If
Next

ArrService2Search = Array(_
                            "Adobe",_
                            "Bits",_
                            "GoogleChromeElevationService",_
                            "gupdate",_
                            "gupdatem",_
                            "sedsvc",_
                            "SynTPEnhService"_
                        )
Services = Dico.Keys

' Looking for a service name in this array ArrService2Search :
For each Service2Search in ArrService2Search 
    For each ServiceName in Services
        PathName = Dico(ServiceName)
        If Instr(UCASE(ServiceName),UCASE(Service2Search)) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "The service : " & chr(34) & ServiceName & chr(34) & " Exists !" & vbcrlf &_
            "Path : "& chr(34) & PathName & chr(34),vbInformation,Title
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: You could take this a stage further and make it a re-usable function instead of just a one-off script, i.e. `ExistsValue(d, Capital2Search)`. Good answer though.

Comment: Hey I wanted to use this logic in pulling objects from query to fetch wmi services and put them in dictionary if the service matches in the dictionary it should print. Can you please help me with the example

Here is what I'm using to fetch the objects:
Set colSWbemObjectSet = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery _
   ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service")

Comment: @NikshepAKulli Please First : You should accept this as an answer before and you should formulate another question for that, and show us some effort and post it in a new question for that and you can refer for this. and describe more your issue if you have stuck on it. and don't forget to mentione in your new question the service name that you are looking for ! Good Luck !

Comment: @NikshepAKulli Check my last edit code and don't forget to mark it as an answer in this case !

Comment: @Hackoo I'm sorry, I tried posting it as a new question but I was not able to, I'm new to stackoveflow, I will definately accept this answer Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: @Hackoo I have posted one my new doubt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63774694/i-want-to-use-wildcards-to-compare-strings-in-second-method-service2search

Comment: Could you please share ur thoughts on same

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63776283/how-can-i-wildcard-in-regex-method-i-have-written-in-my-method here is the new question regarding same I don't know for some reason they closed my old question